# Convert all Excel cells in text format and print into export | C# MVC 5

Tags: c#, excel, gridview, export

i need to convert all cells in text format, because excel dosn't print number over 10 units.

my code:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = new List<SIM_lista>();           
        var grid = new GridView();

        USR_User user = Session[Costants.Costants.UserSession] as USR_User;

        CoreEntities core = new CoreEntities();
        List<SIM_lista> lista = core.SIM_lista.Where(x => x.SIM_Friendlyname == user.USR_Friendly_Name).OrderByDescending(x => x.SIM_Date_Insert).ToList<SIM_lista>();  

        grid.DataSource = lista;
        grid.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Export_SIM_" + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + ".xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        grid.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();

        return View();

    }
```

i've wanted online but without solution...there's a method that allow to convert all cell in text format ? I want add to my code.

My result now:

[image]

For example in a cell my result is 3,01329E+19, instead I want print SIM_iccid like this 30132880413013288041

ps: the object SIM_Lista have all object as String

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `'` to tell excel the field is a string not a number.

```
List<SIM_lista> lista = core.SIM_lista
.Where(x => x.SIM_Friendlyname == user.USR_Friendly_Name)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.SIM_Date_Insert)
.Select(o=>new SIM_lista(){
    SIM_Id = o.SIM_Id,
    SIM_Date_Insert = o.SIM_Date_Insert,
    SIM_iccid  = "'" + o.SIM_iccid 
}).ToList<SIM_lista>();
```

Comment: yes your solution works! there is a method to set a "invisible" char ?